# Find missing date range gaps

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

Using MySQL 5.7:

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PersonalActivity (
  subject VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  FromDate DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  ToDate DATE DEFAULT NULL
) ;

SELECT DISTINCT subject, DATE_FORMAT(FromDate, '%Y-%m') as 'from', DATE_FORMAT(ToDate, '%Y-%m') as 'to'
FROM PersonalActivity;
```

Table: Personal Activity
Columns: Subject, FromDate, ToDate

How can I get missing date ranges in YYYY-MM (e.g. FromDate XXXX-XX - ToDate XXXX-XX) format from the table?

Sample Input:

> FromDate | ToDate | Subject
>
> 2010-01 | 2010-04 | work
>
> 2010-08 | 2010-11 | work
>
> 2011-01 | 2011-01 | holidays

Sample Output:

> FromDate | ToDate | Subject
>
> 2010-05 | 2010-07 | N/A
>
> 2010-12 | 2010-12 | N/A

The end goal is to get an output in FromDate, ToDate, and Subject (With NULL or N/A) from the given dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by missing date ranges? Can you provide some sample input/output? Do you mean error handling if a value is null? Or the list of dates that are the gaps between the ranges contained in the tables?

Comment: Make another table with column containing data in form of YYYY-MM for all of dates ... then do the left join

Comment: Agre with @Veljko89 - The standard practice is to have a calendar table with all the dates you'll ever need, to which you can also record if a day is a work day, a bank holiday, or any other meta-data.

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Plz clarify and provide expected data sample.

Comment: Search for the infamous problem of gap and islands with dates.

Comment: @kchason provided sample inlut/output

Comment: @MatBailie but will it show null date ranges?

Comment: @MarcM added sample input/output

Comment: Is is guaranteed to only have one range?

Comment: According to your example, the desired result should provide a row with the range `2011-12 | 2011-12 | N/A` too, shouldn't it? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza yes, correct.

Comment: Your are trying to find out gaps in your dates sequence between `MIN(FromDate)` and `MAX(ToDate)`. One approach is to find out the 'time distance' (i.e. distance in months may work in this case) from each date to the beginning of the sequence `MIN(FromDate)`. Then, comparing distances you may detect 'the gaps'. Solution is not trivial. I recommend you to read carefully [Data boundaries: Finding gaps, islands, and more][https://www.sqlshack.com/data-boundaries-finding-gaps-islands-and-more/] looking for coding inspiration. I think one of the firsts examples may fit your needs.